# Modal Dialog with WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dialog

There are tons and tons of articles around the internet about this topic, but I just can't wrap my head around it. Most articles use code behind, but I want to stick to "pure" MVVM since I try to learn it. Also, I explicitly don't want to use any other framework (MVVMlight, Ninject...). I just want to stick to what WPF has to offer. I know this got asked a lot, but what I found either was not mvvm or was not specific enough.

My task is simple: I want to see the most simple solution of opening a modal dialog, send it a string, and get a string from the dialog back upon closing it.

Therefore I set up my MainWindow.xaml with a text input field (TextBox), a button (that should open the modal dialog) and a textblock that will show the message I intend to receive from the dialog.

The dialog has a TextBlock, showing the user-input from MainWindow.xaml, and a TextBox to enter some text, and a button. You guessed it: you press the button, and the message I typed into the textfield get's returned to MainWindow.xaml. Please refer also to the images I've included - I think it's pretty self-explanatory.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Dialogs.MainWindow"
     ...
Title="First View (Main Window)" Height="240" Width="630">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
            <TextBlock Text="Main View sayz: "/>
            <TextBox Width="360" Margin="10,0,0,30"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Button Content="Send to Second View" Command="{Binding SendToSecondViewCommand}" Width="200"/>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,30,10,10">
            <TextBlock Text="Second View replies: "/>
            <TextBlock Width="360"/>
        </StackPanel>           

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

SecondView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Dialogs.SecondView"
    ...
d:DesignHeight="240" d:DesignWidth="630" Background="BlanchedAlmond">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
            <TextBlock Text="This is what First View sayz: "/> 
            <TextBlock Width="360"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
            <TextBlock Text="Second View replies: "/>
            <TextBox Width="360" Margin="10,0,0,30"/>
        </StackPanel>

            <Button Content="Reply to First View" Command="{Binding ReplyToFirstViewCommand}" Width="200"/>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is how I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged (It's actually a .cs file named BaseClasses; I know it's not named properly...)

```
public abstract class NotifyPropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{        
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged<T>(ref T variable, T value,
                    [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        variable = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And here my base class for relay commands:

```
public class CommandDelegateBase : ICommand
{        
    public delegate void ExecuteDelegate(object parameter);

    public delegate bool CanExecuteDelegate(object paramerter);

    private ExecuteDelegate execute;

    private CanExecuteDelegate canExecute;

    public CommandDelegateBase(ExecuteDelegate _execute, CanExecuteDelegate _canExecute = null)
    {
        execute = _execute;
        canExecute = _canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return canExecute?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        execute.Invoke(parameter);
    }

}
```

Lastly my ViewModels:
FirstViewModel:

```
public class FirstViewViewModel: NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private string _sendText;
    public string SendText
    {
        get { return _sendText; }
        set
        {
            _sendText = value;

            OnPropertyChanged(ref _sendText, value);
        }
    }

    public ICommand SendToSecondViewCommand { get; set; }

    public FirstViewViewModel()
    {
        SendToSecondViewCommand = new CommandDelegateBase(SendExecuteCommand, SendCanExecuteCommand);
    }

    private bool SendCanExecuteCommand(object paramerter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void SendExecuteCommand(object parameter)
    {
        //Do stuff to :
        // a) show the second view as modal dialog
        // b) submit what I just wrote (SendText)
    }
}
```

SecondViewModel:

```
public class SecondViewViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private string _replyText;
    public string ReplyText
    {
        get { return _replyText; }
        set
        {
            _replyText = value;

            OnPropertyChanged(ref _replyText, value);
        }
    }

    public ICommand ReplyToFirstViewCommand { get; set; }

    public SecondViewViewModel()
    {
        ReplyToFirstViewCommand = new CommandDelegateBase(ReplyExecuteCommand, ReplyCanExecuteCommand);
    }

    private bool ReplyCanExecuteCommand(object paramerter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void ReplyExecuteCommand(object parameter)
    {
        //Do stuff to :
        // a) close the second view 
        // b) reply what I just wrote (ReplyText) back to First View.
    }
}
```

I have a folder called "Models" in my solution but for the sake of simplicity it's empty.

I know there are solutions with helper classes or services - what ever pertains mvvm will do. I also do know that doing this for such a simple task as what I want is quiet "overkill", and has a lot more writing code coming with it than it would be justifyable for this purpose. But again: I'd like to learn this, and understand what I am doing.

Thank you so much in advance!

[image: MainWindow.xaml]
[image: SecondView.xaml]
[image: Structure of my solution]

Comment: You may have a look at my [CleanArchitecture project](https://github.com/SirRufo/CleanArchitecture/tree/master/Desktop) where I just added the Dialog feature

Comment: Thank you for your link - noob question: is there any folder I should pay certain attention to? Like "Desktop.WpfApp" or Desktop.Application? The way I understand this, these folders represent complete wpf-solutions to opened in Visual Studio?

Comment: It is a single WPF application with separated projects for the layers (Application, Infrastructure, Presentation and the WPF-Platform).

Comment: Definition of the DialogService: https://github.com/SirRufo/CleanArchitecture/tree/master/Desktop/Desktop.Presentation/Common/Interfaces

Comment: Declaring the Dialog arguments: https://github.com/SirRufo/CleanArchitecture/tree/master/Desktop/Desktop.Presentation/Dialogs

Comment: Implementing the Dialog-Handlers: https://github.com/SirRufo/CleanArchitecture/tree/master/Desktop/Desktop.WpfApp/Handlers/Dialogs

Comment: Don't use some DialogService! It's not a good design. If you _really_ need to show windows from the view model, then use a view model first approach. Follow [Mark Feldman's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61218212/3141792) answer. But seriously consider to change you design first. View logic should _never_ go into the view model.The requirement to do so could be a serious hint that your implementing a bad design - from an MVVM point of view, an anti-pattern.

Comment: Your current described scenario conflicts with the title of your post or the question. If your second view you want to show is a `UserControl` it's never modal, except you draw it on top of a transparent rectangle that stretches full screen to cover the application to intercept user input from being send to secondary application views. All answers here target a scenario were you want to show a dialog like `Window.ShowDialog` from the view model (too complicated and not recommended). If you just want to show a screen or page there are far simpler solutions.

Comment: Also there is absolutely nothing wrong in writing code-behind logic, although this is religiously believed and stubbornly propagated by many. But this shouldn't be about religion. It's about logic. MVVM has only one purpose: separate view from business logic. It doesn't care about the `partial` directive or in other words code-behind. As long as you don't move view logic to the view model you are fine. Most view related business e.g., logic and layout should be implemented in XAML, as this far more convenient and readable.

Comment: You are perfectly fine to create and show a `Window` in code-behind, then collect the data from the window's `DataContext` and send it to the main view model. You also could give the dialog view model a direct reference to the main view model in order to delegate the collected data. The solution depends on whether you want to show a custom dialog implemented as `UserControl` or an OS level modal dioalog using `Window.ShowDialog`.

Comment: This _"No-Code-Behind"_ mantra tries to enlighten Winforms developers.

Answer (score 1):

I [wrote an article about this subject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820324/Implementing-Dialog-Boxes-in-MVVM) and provided a library and sample application. The article itself is long...because it's not a trivial topic...but causing a dialog box to appear can be as simple as this:

```
this.Dialogs.Add(new CustomDialogBoxViewModel()); // dialog box appears here
```

UPDATE: I just noticed that my MvvmDialogs library in that package is actually referencing MvvmLite. That's a vestigial remnant from when I was developing it though, the library itself doesn't need it, so you can remove the reference altogether.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's a lot of text, and I'll need some time to go through it. The line of code you provided in your reply does need some preparation in the  calling view's .xaml, doesn't it? Or do you just raise a call to the view? But then again: how would the view be shown, by calling the viewmodel? And considering alltogether that the viewmodel should know noting about it's view? Maybe you could point out an answer, as I am sure, others seeking help mind find it usefull, too.

Comment: It is a lot of text, but you don't need to read it all in order to use the library. With respect to your question, you do need to add a behavior in your MainWindow which binds to your Dialogs collection; it handles everything for you after that. You also need to create DataTemplates...one for each of your dialog box types...so that the behavior knows which view to create for any given view model, but that's just 3 lines of very simple XML. Best thing to do would be to have a look at the last section of my article, that will help you determine whether it's appropriate for your case. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Finding an MVVM pure solution to a programming problem, which may be straightforward in other contexts, is often not a simple task. However, creating a library of helper classes is a "write once, use many times" scenario, so no matter how much code is required, you don't have to reproduce it for every usage.

My preferred method for handling message dialogs in MVVM is a two part service module.

1. The View registers its data context (its ViewModel) with the DialogService as potentially wanting to display a dialog - the service will use the View's UI context to do so when it does.
2. The ViewModel calls the injected dialog service each time a dialog should be displayed. Calls to the MessageDialog service are made using the async / await pattern, rather than requiring some other form of callback in the ViewModel.

So now, displaying a MessageDialog from a ViewModel is as simple as

```
await _dialogService.ShowMessageAsync(this, "Hello from the dialog service.", perDialogIcon.Information, "Mvvm Dialog Service").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

or

```
var response = await _dialogService.ShowDialogAsync(this, perDialogButton.YesNo, "Do you want to continue?", perDialogIcon.Question, "Mvvm Dialog Service").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I covered this in more detail on a [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/mvvm-message-dialogs/).

As an aside, your ViewModel properties look a bit wierd - you're setting the backing-field value, then passing it into your `OnPropertyChanged()` method where the value is set again.

Comment: The OP wants to have a modal dialog of a view bound to SecondViewViewModel. You showed how to wrap MessageBox dialogs.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I just flew over it: is it especially about MessageBoxes or can it be applied to modal dialogs as well (I know, a bit of the same case, but I want to interchange data, and not only react to DialogResults). About the "weird" viewmodel: you are right :) I sometimes forget that I reference the value, and got it done all in one go with my OnPropertyChanged-event.